# How can I configure my Ubuntu so that my web page in Apache Server can be displayed on the internet?

Tags: server, apache2, internet

I use Ubuntu and I have my web page, it is in Apache, my internet connection is through a router. Investigating a little I could show my web page in the local area, opening port 80. Now I want to be able to show it on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to forward port 80 from your router to your server. further instruction vary depending on your router's model and firmware (or OS, but I doubt you would ask this question if you had a desktop or server running a router service)

Some ISPs will block port 80, usually in this case you can use port 443 (https) or pick a different port number like 81